# Microsoft Graph - Proper way to retrieve attendance report from an Event

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft-graph-calendar

**CONTEXT**

Using application permission i'm creating an event and then retrieve the attendance report from it.

**CODE TO ADD EVENT**

```
  public static async Task<Event> CreateEventAsync(string emailUser, Event @event, string calendarId)
        {
            try
            {
                // Add /Events
                return await graphClient.Users[emailUser].Calendars[calendarId].Events
                    .Request()
                    .AddAsync(@event);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new MosException(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

**CODE TO GET ATTENDANCE REPORT**

```
GraphHelper.Initialize();
var organizer = await GraphHelper.GetUserAsync(emailUser);
var reponseCalendar = await GraphHelper.GetCalendarAsync(emailUser);
var graphUserId = organizer.Id;

var linktoWebUrl = "/onlineMeetings?$filter=JoinWebUrl%20eq%20'https://teams.microsoft.com/l/meetup-join/19%3ameeting_YTEz.....etc...'";

var linkGraph = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/" + graphUserId + linktoWebUrl;

var accessToken = GraphHelper.GetToken().Result;
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var apiCaller = new ProtectedApiCallHelper(httpClient);
var meetingObject = await apiCaller.CallWebApiAndGetASync(linkGraph, accessToken);

var meeetingIdJson = meetingObject.Last.First.First.First.Last;//<- not cool :(
var meeetingId = meeetingIdJson.ToString();

var newLink = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/" + graphUserId + "/onlineMeetings/" + meeetingId + "/attendanceReports ";
var meetingOnline = await apiCaller.CallWebApiAndGetASync(newLink, accessToken);

var attendanceReportsByUrl = meetingOnline.Last.First.First;//<- not cool :(
```

**RESPONSE**

[image: Response]

**PROBLEME**

Is there a way to do it in a proper way BUT, of course, from an Event and not an OnlineMeeting?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, what you mentioned `<- not cool` can be solved when using graph client sdk like what you did in `add event` in my opinion. You can then avoid using code like `.Last.First`.

Then your ultimate goal is getting `attendance report`, so you have to using `OnlineMeeting` instead of `Event` because [the api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/meetingattendancereport-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) is provided by Online meeting.

And you may try code below, and I noticed that you used `/beta` version api, so you need to use the **beta version SDK** if you want to continue to use beta version:

[image]

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Azure.Identity;

public async Task<string> getReportAsync() {
    var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
    var tenantId = "your_tenant_name.onmicrosoft.com";
    var clientId = "azure_ad_clientid";
    var clientSecret = "client_secret";
    var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
        tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
    var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

    //isOnlineMeeting and onlineMeeting don't support filtering, so using Event is not a good choice
    //var events = await graphClient.Users["user_id"].Events
    //            .Request()
    //            .Select("isOnlineMeeting,onlineMeeting")
    //            .GetAsync();

    var meeting = await graphClient.Users["user_id"].OnlineMeetings
                    .Request()
                    .Filter("JoinWebUrl eq 'join_url'")
                    //.Select("id")
                    .GetAsync();
    var meetingId = meeting.FirstOrDefault().Id;

    var attendanceReports = await graphClient.Users["user_id"].OnlineMeetings[meetingId].AttendanceReports
                            .Request()
                            .GetAsync();
    return "success";
}
```

Comment: In my particular context i'm working with Event so is not possible for me to simply use OnlineMeeting instead, and I'm using the beta only for testing purpose. But thanks anyway for your suggestion.

Comment: "can be solved when using graph client sdk like what you did in add event" --> after some research i didn't find the equivalent request that retrieve a meeting by JoinWebUrl parameter.